# Estimation of fraction of integrals

Tags: integration, analysis, fractions, estimation

(*edited for more clarity*)

For a given function $f$, which is continuous, and $a < b$ real numbers, 
I need to make an estimation of the type
$ \Bigg| \frac{\int_a^b f(t) (-t)dt}{\int_a^b f(t)dt} \Bigg| \leq M $. That is to say, I want to find the minimal $M$ with that property.

(1) Are there any tricks for estimating this for such general $f$?

(2) I could further assume for my application that $f$ is positive... then my best result is that $a \leq M \leq b$, because
$f(t)a \leq f(t)t \leq f(t) b \quad \forall t \in [a,b]$
Does somebody have an idea how to improve these bounds?

Comment: Is $f$ a polynomial function?

Comment: No, it is just an arbitrary continous function

Comment: If $f$ isn't positive, the LHS can very well be unbounded (take any odd function in $[-a,a]$).

Comment: If you can bound $f$ below and above with functions that you can integrate, you can get tighter estimates. But I don't think you can find the minimal $M$ without solving the exact integrals.

Comment: If I do find functions s.t. $g(x) \leq f(x) \leq h(x)$ on $[a,b]$, is it valid to say that $\Bigg|\frac{\int_a^b f(t) (-t) dt}{\int_a^b f(t) dt} \Bigg| \leq \Bigg| \frac{\int_a^b h(t) (-t) \ dt }{\int_a^b g(t) dt} \Bigg|$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Well the estimation $$(b-a)\cdot \min_{x\in [a,b]}\{f(x)\}\leq \int_a^b f(x)dx \leq (b-a)\cdot  \max_{x\in [a,b]}\{f(x)\}$$

is an *exact* estimation (i.e., we can find functions for which both inequalities become equalities), so with no other info about $f$, it's the best you can do...

Comment: Ok, yes. I was just hoping that I could multiply out something, such that a lot cancels. But apparently not.

Comment: Mh, is this enough to say anything about the inequation in the OP ?

Comment: I think the answer was referring to something in my original post, but I have updated it. Using the mean value theorem does not yield enough for what I am trying to do...